# "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException" on AlertDialog.Builder#show even with safeguards

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-fragmentactivity

I'm receiving the `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException` exception, even with (what I understand to be all the necessary) safeguards around the creation and displaying of the dialog.

Here's an equivalent to the code that creates and displays the dialog:

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity

    public void handleErrorDialogOk() {
        ...
    }

    public void makeErrorDialog(){
        if (!isFinishing()){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (isFinishing())
                        return;

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MyFragmentActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Some title")
                        .setMessage("Some message")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                handleErrorDialogOk();
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

I'm not seeing it all the time, it seems to be random and I'm unable to reproduce it (only seeing it in the `ANRs & crashes` tab of the play store on the released app).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Or could this be a bug with `FragmentActivity`? I don't seem to see it occurring with any `AlertDialogs` that are presented from instances of classes that derive from the standard `Activity` class...

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs when you are trying to create a dialog in the Activity, but the Activity has already finished. The window is no longer avaialable.So, change context :

```
 if(!context.isFinishing()){ 
 //FragmentActivity is the context
  builder.show();
  }
```

Comment: but I'm already checking that the presenting context isn't finishing, both before posting to the main thread, then again before the dialog is actually shown

Answer (score 0):

Upon further examination of the play store crash/ANR data, I noticed that this only occurs on a specific Android version; and as noted originally in my question, it only happens on classes that derive from `FragmentActivity`, which leads me to conclude that there must be some kind of bug in the `FragmentActivity` impl on that Android version, as I am taking all precautions that I understand to be necessary to avoid presenting a dialog on a destroying activity (which is the usual cause for this exception).